# GWT validate time entered into a textbox - error when converting type Long result to 24 hour format

Tags: java, gwt

I am using the following answer to validate the time entered into a textbox:

[Parsing user time input in Java/GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683279/parsing-user-time-input-in-java-gwt)

This returns milliseconds in Long format. So now I want to convert that to 24 hour format. So I use this suggestion:

```
long startTime = parseTime(textBoxStartTime.getText());
long second = (startTime / 1000) % 60;
long minute = (startTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
long hour = (startTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
```

Based on:

[java convert milliseconds to time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format)

However, I get the following error when I compile:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Glyndwr/workspace/AwardTracker_N/src/org/AwardTracker/client/HikeDetailsView.java'
      [ERROR] Line 387: The method format(String, long, long, long) is undefined for the type String
```

I have also tried:

```
String startTimeString = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH:mm").format(startTime);
```

Which gives the error:

```
Thee method format(Date) in the type DateTimeFormat is not applicable for the arguments (long)
```

Answer (score 1):

GWT does not emulate all the methods in *java.lang.String*. So you cannot use the method `public static String format(String format, Object... args)` in GWT.

You can use the following code instead.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.append(hour).append(":").append(minute).append(":").append(second);
String time =sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
String startTimeString = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(startTime));
```

If time zone is important, you need to pass TimeZone to the `format` method in addition to Date.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank you very much for your help and this almost works. However, all times are ahead 11 hours (e.g., if I enter 02:00 then the milliseconds returned are 7200000 (correct) which should be 02:00 hours, however 13:00 is returned from the formatting). Time zone is not important to me. If I enter 2 am I want 02:00 returned.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
long startTime = parseTime(textBoxStartTime.getText());
int i = (int) startTime;
int minute = (i / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
String formattedMinute = NumberFormat.getFormat("00").format(minute);
int hour = (i / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
String formattedHour = NumberFormat.getFormat("00").format(hour);
String time = null;
time = formattedHour + ":" + formattedMinute;
textBoxStartTime.setText(time);
```